# How to get the avg time between dates on 2 separated querysets

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have a parking place spot app finder built in Django and Flutter, and I want to make an API call where I can get the average time of all reservations done until today, being the average time `(end_time - init_time) / total_reservations`

I have 2 querysets, one for all the `init_time` and the other for all the `end_time` whick are the following:

```
qs1 = Reservation.objects.values('init_time_reservation')
qs2 = Reservation.objects.values('end_time_reservation')
```

Is there a way to make that? I'm using Django for all my backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a timedelta object by doing

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F, Count, ExpressionWrapper, DateTimeField

avg_time = Sum(F('end_time')-F('init_time'))/Count('id')
Reservation.objects.aggregate(avg_time=ExpressionWrapper(avg_time, output_field=DateTimeField())
```

[Django docs on aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/)

Comment: That's not what I really needed, both end_time and init_time are querysets, not values, and I need to return an integer not a field

Comment: Maybe provide more information in your question. You could put the code for your models.